Reference request: $K^0(X) \cong K_0(X)$ for smooth schemes $X$
Where can I find a proof that for a smooth scheme $X$,
$$
K^0(X) \cong K_0(X)?
$$
This is stated on Wikipedia as known https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-theory#Grothendieck_group_of_vector_bundles_in_algebraic_geometry.
I am in particular interested in an explicit isomorphism.

Note that there is always a map
$$\label{eq:1}\tag{1}K^0(X) \to K_0(X),$$
by considering a vector bundle $E$ as a locally free sheaf (its sheaf of sections). This is well-defined because every short exact sequence of vector bundles yields a short exact sequence of corresponding sheaves.
Conversely, every short exact sequence of locally free sheaves is also a short exact sequence of vector bundles, so this map is actually injective.
It remains to show that the map is surjective, when $X$ is smooth. To do this, it suffices to find for every coherent sheaf $F$ on $X$ a resolution
$$\label{eq:2}\tag{2}0 \to E_n \to E_{n-1} \to \dotsb \to E_1 \to E_0 \to F \to 0,$$
where the $E_i$ are vector bundles. Given such a resolution, you have $[F] = \sum_i (-1)^i [E_i]$ in $K_0(X)$, and since the right hand side comes from $K^0(X)$, this shows the required surjectivity.
Let's assume for simplicity that $X$ is quasi-projective[1]. Then there exists an ample line bundle $\mathcal O_X(1)$. Given a sheaf $F$, twisting high enough will make it globally generated, i.e. the map
$$H^0(X, F(n)) \otimes \mathcal O_X \to F(n)$$
is surjective. Twisting back you get a surjection
$$E_0 := H^0(X, F(n)) \otimes \mathcal O_X(-n) \to F \to 0.$$
Repeating the argument for the kernel $K_0 \subset E_0$, and so on, you get a resolution
$$\dotsb \to E_2 \to E_1 \to E_0 \to F \to 0$$
by locally free sheaves $E_i$. (This should remind you of how to resolve a module over a ring by projective modules.)
Note however, that this resolution does not have to be finite, but we also haven't used the smoothness yet!
Let $n = \dim X$ be the dimension, and let $\tilde E_n \subset E_{n-1}$ be the kernel of the map $E_{n-1} \to E_{n-2}$. Since $X$ is smooth, its local rings are all regular of dimension $n$. By a theorem of Serre, a regular local ring has global dimension $n$. This implies that $\tilde E_n$ has to be locally free, i.e. a vector bundle. Hence the sequence
$$0 \to \tilde E_n \to E_{n-1} \to \dotsb \to E_0 \to F \to 0$$
is a finite resolution of $F$ by vector bundles.

[1] If $X$ is not quasi-projective, but still a noetherian regular scheme, you can still obtain resolutions by vector bundles. See Hartshorne, Algebraic Geometry, Exercise 6.8 or SGA 6, Exposé II, Prop 2.2.7.

The definition of $K^0(X)$ that I know of goes via direct sums (see the explicit construction in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_group), how can I see that that definition is equivalent to the one you are using (via exact sequneces)?

For the general case, every separated noetherian locally factorial scheme (i.e. any separated smooth scheme over a field, since a regular local ring is a UFD) has the resolution property, see SGA 6 Exp. II, prop 2.2.7.

@fish_monster In algebraic geometry you really want to use short exact sequences, because not every short exact sequence of sheaves (or algebraic vector bundles) splits. (As opposed to e.g. topology, because where you can always choose a metric on your vector bundle, and then identify the cokernel with the orthogonal complement of the kernel, so every short exact sequence splits).

@KReiser Thanks for the reference, I didn't know that!

@KReiser Could you elaborate on that a bit further?

@fish_monster the resolution property is the property that every coherent sheaf is the quotient of a locally free sheaf of finite rank. This will let you construct the resolution $$\cdots\to E_1\to E_0\to F\to 0$$ in the above answer, then you can proceed onwards with the same logic as in the answer.

@red_trumpet happy to help! +1 for a solid answer.

@KReiser I'm still confused about how that shows that the Grothendieck group construction given in that Wikipedia article (using the product and modding out by direct sums) ties to the one given via the exact sequence way.

@fish_monster It doesn't, KReiser's comment addresses a different point in my answer. As far as I understand, you get a different group if you only consider relations coming from direct sums. I have never seen this studied in the context of algebraic geometry though, and I guess it is not very useful.

"Conversely, every short exact sequence of locally free sheaves is also a short exact sequence of vector bundles, so this map is actually injective." I think this step is missing some details. In $K_0(X)$, we quotient by various short exact sequences involving locally free sheaves in one or two of the 3 positions. How do we know this doesn't introduce additional relations among locally free sheaves? I think the answer is the horseshoe lemma.
